# Send email with HTML signature, the signature is in html code

Tags: google-apps-script

Referring to [this thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41727640/apps-script-to-get-the-users-signature/41729412#41729412) I'm able to retrieve my signature from Gmail with the code `var signature = Gmail.Users.Settings.SendAs.list("me").sendAs.filter(function(account){if(account.isDefault){return true}})[0].signature;`

But if I attach the retrieved HTML to the email body, the recipient see the raw code instead of my signature.
I red many threads with this problem, but I'm unable to understand how fix this, I'm not expert with HTML.
Please could someone help me?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`GmailApp` allows you to parse html using `htmlBody`:

```
var signature = Gmail.Users.Settings.SendAs.list("me").sendAs.filter(function(account){if(account.isDefault){return true}})[0].signature;
GmailApp.sendEmail("email@gmaiil.com", "signature test", "test", {htmlBody: signature})
```

---

#### Update:

The signature of `GmailApp.sendEmail` is:

1. `sendEmail(recipient, subject, body, options)`

or:

2. `sendEmail(recipient, subject, body)`

In your case, you need to use option 1.

`replyTo` is specified using the `options` object.

So, to summarize, here is your code:

```
mia_firma = '<p>' + corpo + '</p>' + mia_firma; // concat htmlBody
MailApp.sendEmail(dest, // recipient email - string
                  sogg, // should be subject - string
                  corpo, // mail body - WILL BE IGNORED if you use htmlBody
                  { // options - object
                      htmlBody: mia_firma,
                      replyTo: "reply_to@XYZ.page"
                  }
);
```

You can see the full documentation [here](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/gmail/gmail-app#sendemailrecipient,-subject,-body,-options)

Comment: Thank you for your suggestion Elchanan, but it doesnt work. I get an error "Exception: The parameters (String,String,String,String,(class)) don't match the method signature for MailApp.sendEmail."

Comment: the sentence I wrote is: "MailApp.sendEmail(dest, "reply_to@XYZ.page", sogg, corpo, {htmlBody: mia_firma});" dest=recipient email, sogg=object, corpo=mail body.

Comment: Great, can you mark the answer as correct (green V)? :)